# DDL statements against deleted inserted in DML trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, dml

I am trying to find impact of doing DDL statement against deleted and inserted logical tables inside table trigger. I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger52]
ON [dbo].[Table1]
FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
     create table inserted (c1 int)
     select * from inserted                        
END
```

When it is triggered, I expected to get an error. Instead, it seems to ignore create table statement entirely and select rows that have been inserted.

Is there a documentation describing this behavior or explanation?

Comment: This is as-specified. SQL Server provides an "inserted" table (assuming this is SQL Server). Why are you trying to create a table in the trigger in the first place?

Comment: Get rid of : `create table inserted (c1 int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside triggers there are always two pseudo-tables existing: `inserted` and `deleted`. See [Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> SQL Server automatically creates and
>   manages these tables. You can use
>   these temporary, memory-resident
>   tables to test the effects of certain
>   data modifications and to set
>   conditions for DML trigger actions.
>   You cannot directly modify the data in
>   the tables or perform data definition
>   language (DDL) operations on the
>   tables.